# Use limit comparison test to show that an integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that $$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}x^p\ dx$$ converges for every $p$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that I need to use the limit comparison test with $x^{-2}$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, first of all write down what the lmit comparison test is...

Comment: Sure-  one seeks to show that the integrand is bounded above by a monotonic, decreasing function.So the problem is to show that $x^{-2}$ is greater than $e^{-x}x^{p}$ for any p.

Comment: for every $b$ there is $a$ such that $e^{-(x+a)} < x^{-b}$ for every $x > 1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^p \leq e^{\frac{1}{2} x}$, for $x\geq x_p$ (for some fixed $x_p>1$). Define $f_p$ by:
$$f_p(x) = \begin{cases} \max_{1 \leq x\leq x_p}(e^{\frac{1}{2}x},x^p), \quad \mbox{for $1\leq x \leq x_p$ }\\
e^{\frac{1}{2}x} \quad \mbox{, for $x>x_p$} \end{cases}$$

Then:

$$ \int_1^\infty e^{-x} x^p dx \leq \int_1^{x_p} e^{-x}f_p(x)dx +\int_{x_p}^\infty {e^{-x}e^{\frac{1}{2}x}dx}\leq \max_{1 \leq x\leq x_p}(e^{\frac{1}{2}x},x^p) (x_p-1)+\int_{x_p}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2} x} dx < \infty$$

Comment: how do you know that $x^p \leq e^{\frac{1}{2}x}$? How do you know that this holds for all $p$ ?

Comment: Sorry - I was too hasty. I've corrected the argument.